# Double feature: Braaains

Tags: grid-deduction, cryptic-crosswords

<sub>This puzzle is part 1 of the Double feature series. The series will continue in "*[Double feature: Russian desman](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90055)*".</sub>

---

> [image]
>
> Rules of **Akari** (also known as Light Up)<sup>1</sup>
>
> - Insert light bulbs into any number of empty cells.
> - Black cells are walls and cannot contain light bulbs.
> - Numbers in black cells indicate how many light bulbs are directly adjacent to that cell (vertically and horizontally).
> - A light bulb illuminates its own cell as well as every cell visible from it in all four directions (up/down/right/left), continuing until a wall comes in the way.
> - Every white square must be illuminated by at least one light bulb.
> - No light bulb may be illuminated by another light bulb.
>
> **Across**
> 2. Otherwise heartless woman of Beethoven's dedication (4)
> 5. Major city identified in articles about John Fogerty's band (5)
> 7. A major criminal organization? (5)
> 8. Martial artist striking left and right to draw blood (3)
> 9. Rating below "unlimited" (3)
> 11. Chapeau smuggled in chateau (3)
> 13. 0.0000001% of an iPod (4)
> 15. Uranium extracted from unopened, rusty pen (3)
> 16. Primary meal ingredients: mostly soy soup from Japan (4)
> 17. "Whatever!" – Warhol after losing final bid (3)
> 19. Disagreements follow key goods being held by third parties (7)
>
> **Down**
> 1. Jimmy and Jack – sort of same (5)
> 3. Some fail at choosing door fastener (5)
> 4. Force out during surefire victory (5)
> 5. Enthusiastic interstellar hitchhiker not hurt, amazingly (6)
> 6. Sri Lanka once got rid of mathematical constant – Number Six, maybe (5)
> 10. Zealous leader leaving lethargic place (3)
> 12. In the morning, a space station is out of order (5)
> 14. One's first impression is what can be heard in 15 across (4)
> 15. Central Missouri is left bitter (4)
> 18. Almost double what can be heard in 5 across (3)
>
> <sub><sup>1</sup> Paraphrased from the original rules on [Nikoli](http://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/akari.html).</sub>

Solve both puzzles to answer the question: **What are zombies?**

Comment: Hey @jafe! I was wondering if I would be able to feature your puzzles on another website. Of course, I would give you full credit and hopefully more people could enjoy these wonderful puzzles!

Comment: @ThatOneNerdyBoy Of course, feel free :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What are zombies?

> **SCARIEST MONSTERS**

Solutions to the cryptic:

> ```
> Across
> 2. Otherwise heartless woman of Beethoven's dedication (4)            ELSE = für EL(i)SE
> 5. Major city identified in articles about John Fogerty's band (5)    ACCRA = A + CCR + A
> 7. A major criminal organization? (5)                                 TRIAD (dd)
> 8. Martial artist striking left and right to draw blood (3)           (Bruce) LEE = (b)LEE(d)
> 9. Rating below "unlimited" (3)                                       ELO = (b)ELO(w)
> 11. Chapeau smuggled in chateau (3)                                   c_HAT_eau
> 13. 0.0000001% of an iPod (4)                                         NANO (dd)
> 15. Uranium extracted from unopened, rusty pen (3)                    STY = (r)(u)STY
> 16. Primary meal ingredients: mostly soy soup from Japan (4)          MISO = M_ I_ + SO(y)
> 17. "Whatever!" - Warhol after losing final bid (3)                   ANY = AN(d)Y
> 19. Disagreements follow key goods being held by third parties (7)    ESCROWS = ESC + ROWS
>
> Down
> 1. Jimmy and Jack - sort of same (5)                                  JAMES = J + SAME*
> 3. Some fail at choosing door fastener (5)                            LATCH = fai_L AT CH_oosing
> 4. Force out during surefire victory (5)                              EVICT = surefir_E VICT_ory
> 5. Enthusiastic interstellar hitchhiker not hurt, amazingly (6)       ARDENT = AR(thur*) DENT
> 6. Sri Lanka once got rid of mathem. const. - Number Six, maybe (5)   CYLON = CE(y)LON
> 10. Zealous leader leaving lethargic place (3)                        LAY = LA(z)Y
> 12. In the morning, a space station is out of order (5)               AMISS = AM + ISS
> 14. One's first impression is what can be heard in 15 across (4)      OINK! = O(ne) + INK
> 15. Central Missouri is left bitter (4)                               SOUR = (m)(is)SOUR(i)
> 18. Almost double what can be heard in 5 across (3)                   TWI = TWI(n)?
> ```

Filled-in grids:

> [image: Shine a light on the crypticism]

Comment: Everything's correct. Nice work!

Comment: Ninjaed by three minutes!

Comment: (7a may be clarified by considering the first two words of the clue.)

Comment: I had a feeling I needed to be quick ... Didn't know that meaning of 7a and had to look it up.

Comment: I'm not sure about 1d.    I'm taking Jimmy as the definition, and  the anagram indicator is fine, but I don't see how Jack gives me a 'J'

Comment: I think your parsing on 15 D should be ISSOUR (Central Missouri) - IS (is left) = SOUR,

Comment: @ChrisCudmore: You are right about IS leaving central Missouri. J is the letter used for an on the playing card.