# Double feature: Russian desman

Tags: grid-deduction, cryptic-crosswords, masyu, printers-devilry

<sub>This puzzle is part 2 of the Double feature series (first part [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90029)). The series will continue in "*[Double feature: In concert](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90163)*".</sub>

---

> [image]
>
> Rules of **Masyu**<sup>1</sup>
>
> - Make a single loop which goes through every white and black circle in the grid.
> - The line passes through centres of cells and makes 90-degree turns only.
> - The line cannot cross itself or branch off in multiple directions.
> - When passing through a white circle, the line must go straight through the circled cell and make a turn directly before or after that cell (or both).
> - When passing through a black circle, the line must make a turn inside the circled cell and continue straight for at least one cell on both sides.
>
> Note: The crossword clues below are a mix of Printer's Devilry and normal cryptic clues.
>
> **Across**
>   1. Mona, rains stop in Nice (4)
>   4. Wet dirt over my puppet (5)
>   7. English county is sorted out (6)
>   8. Therese R's arrived at the scene (4)
>   10. St. Peter guards heavenly gates (5)
>   11. Medication with added sulfur is cause of harm (5)
>   12. Finally a brief tour to do for black people (4)
>   13. Adversary of Yemen in turmoil (5)
>   15. Nose around quietly before raising your heads (3)
>
> **Down**
>   2. State of Hawaii is located within Ontario's borders (4)
>   3. Singing barber is, for the most part, an immature person (4)
>   5. Poor result for one part of Ireland (6)
>   6. The Sesams are sometimes used for other meanings (5)
>   8. I can listen to 2 e-cubes unavailable (7)
>   9. Bottom of broken direction sign is not wide (6)
>   10. Biological distinctions of executive leaders in National Socialist organization  (5)
>   14. Space station's outline seen ascending (3)
>
> <sub><sup>1</sup> Paraphrased from the original rules on [Nikoli](https://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/masyu.html).</sub>

Solve both puzzles to answer the question: **What is the Russian desman?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Partial answer**

The Russian desman

> is a MOLE SPECIES.

After much staring and thinking and dictionary-trawling I remain confused by 8d, which I can't make any sense of either as a p.d. or as an ordinary clue. [EDITED to add: M Oehm figured it out; see below.]

Grids:

> [image]

Explanations:

> 1a. p.d. "Monaco's trains". 4a. MUD<+MY. 7a. SORTED*. 8a. p.d. "responders". 10a. p.d. "Heaven's pearly". 11a. S in CURE (though I claim SPILL is actually a better answer). 12a. A (-brie)F (-tou)R (-t)O. 13a. YEMEN*. 15a. P+R(-aising) Y(-our).
>  2d. HI in O(-ntari)O. 3d. TODD(-ler). 5d. RESULT*. 6d. p.d. "these same terms". 8d. p.d. "2pac if Ice Cube's". 9d. N+ARROW. 10d. EXE(-cutive) in SS. 14d. RIM<.
>  The extracted letters are those on squares that (1) aren't in the Masyu path and (2) aren't blacked out in the crossword.

Credit where due:

> M Oehm figured out 8d; clearly he is more acquainted with the Music Of Today than I am.

Comment: Aaargh! My path was wrong. But I know how 8d works ...

Comment: Also, I ninjaed you by something like 15 seconds. Turnabout is fair play, as they say :-).

Comment: On the other hand, you managed to figure out 8d which confused me completely.

Comment: I'm easy on the ninja'ing. Didn't hear you coming. Turns out my path was correct, but I tried to include the excess letters and couldn't get anywhere. What happened to thinking out of the box?