# Double feature: In concert

Tags: grid-deduction, cryptic-crosswords

<sub>This puzzle is part 3 of the Double feature series (first part [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90029)). The series will continue in "*[Double feature: Hot stuff](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90243)*".</sub>

---

> [image]
>
> Rules of **Ripple Effect**<sup>1</sup>
>
> - Fill the grid so that each cell contains one number.
> - The bold lines divide the grid into rooms. Every room contains consecutive numbers starting from 1. For example, a room of size three will have the numbers 1, 2 and 3 in some order.
> - If there are more than one of the same number on the same row or column, the numbers must have at least as many cells between them as the number indicates. For example, two cells with the number 3 on the same row or column must be separated by at least three cells.
>
> **Across**
>   3. Top removed from crooked talking tree (3)
>   6. A bush for wingless peacock having no energy left (4)
>   7. Drive without a stick (3)
>   8. Writer of *Introductions to Pharaohs of Egypt* (3)
>   9. Oxford educator identifying flower in Russia's south (3)
>   10. French city seen in anime series (5)
>   12. The finale is held in crescendo (3)
>   16. Innumerable? Calculate a smaller amount (9)
>   17. Philistine refusing to boil chicken (3)
>   18. Constructed language words that may be pronounced at the altar (3)
>
> **Down**
>   1. Christian church group of two people rejecting Buddhist mantra (5)
>   2. Pear-shaped harvest (4)
>   4. Fashion tailor's fringe finishing (5)
>   5. A reservoir maker; he lost a rib (4)
>   9. An album of original 1970s music (5)
>   11. Part of TV series *Wild Deep* is receiving Oscar (7)
>   13. Wacky things that go with bolts (4)
>   14. Hybrid talisman discovered (4)
>   15. Periodically upbeat companion (3)
>
> <sub><sup>1</sup> Paraphrased from the original rules on [Nikoli](https://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/ripple_effect.html).</sub>

Solve both puzzles to answer the question: **What is "Clap" by Steve Howe?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is "Clap" by Steve Howe?

> Unaccompanied Solo

Grids

> [image: Solved grids]

Across

3. Top removed from crooked talking tree (3)

> ENT (talking tree, BENT - B)

6. A bush for wingless peacock having no energy left (4)

> COCA (bush, (P)EACOC(K) - E, reversed)

7. Drive without a stick (3)

> ROD (stick, ROAD - A)

8. Writer of Introductions to Pharaohs of Egypt (3)

> POE (writer, initials)

9. Oxford educator identifying flower in Russia's south (3)

> DON (ddef)

10. French city seen in anime series (5)

> NIMES (french city, aNIME Series)

12. The finale is held in crescendo (3)

> END (the finale, crescENDo)

16. Innumerable? Calculate a smaller amount (9)

> COUNTLESS (innumerable, COUNT + LESS)

17. Philistine refusing to boil chicken (3) [Thanks M Oehm]

> HEN (chicken, HEATHEN - HEAT)

18. Constructed language words that may be pronounced at the altar (3)

> IDO (ddef)

Down

1. Christian church group of two people rejecting Buddhist mantra (5)

> DUOMO (christian church, DU(OM)O)

2. Pear-shaped harvest (4)

> REAP (harvest, PEAR anagrammed)

4. Fashion tailor's fringe finishing (5)

> TREND (fashion, TailoR + END)

5. A reservoir maker; he lost a rib (4)

> ADAM (he lost a rib, A + DAM)

9. An album of original 1970s music (5)

> DISCO (1970s music, DISC + O)

11. Part of TV series Wild Deep is receiving Oscar

> (7) EPISODE (part of tv series, EP(ISO)DE)

13. Wacky things that go with bolts (4)

> NUTS (ddef)

14. Hybrid talisman discovered (4) [Thanks M Oehm]

> MULE (hybrid, aMULEt)

15. Periodically upbeat companion (3) [Thanks M Oehm]

> PET (companion, uPbEaT)

Comment: Well done! As for the remaining clues: rot13(9np: [qqrs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_River); 16: URA = (urng)ura; 4: Pbafgehpgvba vf G(nvyb)E + RAQ; 9q: Pbafgehpgvba vf QVFP + 0; 14: ZHYR = (n)ZHYR(g); 15: CRG = (h)C(o)R(n)G)

Comment: @MOehm Thanks for the nice explanations, can you explain the second definition for 9 across?

Comment: Yeah. It's a typical crossword pun: Think what it does and how someone who does it would be called. rot13(Orfvqrf sybjre ~ evire, gurer'f nyfb ahzore ~ rgure naq ohggre ~ enz.)

Comment: A couple of parsings are different than I intended - rot13(qhbzb= qhb + bz onpxjneqf; rcvfbqr = B vafvqr na nantenz bs "vf qrrc") - but the answers are all correct. You get the tick!

Answer (score 4):

Answer

> Unaccompanied Solo

Full Grid

> [image]

Clues @w l doesn't manage to get:

14D

> AURA (wp unknown), def=talisman

15D

> _P_E_T, def=companion