# Double feature: Legal trouble

Tags: grid-deduction, cryptic-crosswords

<sub>This puzzle is part 6 of the Double feature series (first part [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90029)). The series will continue in "*[Double feature: Weightier](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90447)*".</sub>

---

> [image]
>
> Rules of **Hitori**<sup>1</sup>
>
> - Shade some cells in the grid.
> - No number occurs in more than one unshaded cell on any row or column.
> - Shaded cells cannot be adjacent to each other horizontally or vertically, but they may touch at a corner.
> - All unshaded cells are orthogonally connected.
>
> **Across**
>   3. A piece of pork – a shocking starter for Islamist group (5)
>   4. Afterthought by Yankee rapper (3)
>   8. Jaeger skinned an ancient civilization (6)
>   9. Friendly relative disheartened (4)
>   10. Small price to pay for endless soup (3)
>   11. Leased missing central part for saxophone, maybe (4)
>   13. Musical group appearing in Sahara (1-2)
>   14. Middle-Eastern Arabs are nomadic people with no leader (6)
>   16. Tools for measuring leaders (6)
>
> **Down**
>   1. Maybe the awful weather's starting to pass, evoking negative feelings (7)
>   2. Contract man in supporting structures for large computers (10)
>   5. Cossacks secretly making fire (4)
>   6. Stand-up guy with a bit of gentlemen's character (6)
>   7. Prisoner making network's final appearance, ultimately (8)
>   12. Tree's remains after burning (3)
>   13. Lead-free, pure gas containing nitrogen and oxygen (3)
>   15. Original Mad Max held in homeland (3)
>
> <sub><sup>1</sup> Paraphrased from the original rules on [Nikoli](https://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/hitori.html).</sub>

Solve both puzzles to answer the question: **What might an impatient court do?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An impatient court might

> **HASTEN  FORECLOSURE**

Solved crossword grid + Hitori, with explanations for the clues:

> [image: legal_trouble]
>
>  **Across**
>  3. A piece of pork – a shocking starter for *Islamist group* (5) = `HAM + A + S_`
>  4. Afterthought by Yankee *rapper* (3) = `PS + Y`
>  8. Jaeger skinned an *ancient civilization* (6) = `_AEGE_ + AN`
>  9. *Friendly* relative disheartened (4) = `NI(-e)CE`
>  10. *Small price to pay* for endless soup (3) = `SOU(-p)`
>  11. Leased missing central part for *saxophone, maybe* (4) = `RE(-nt)ED`
>  13. *Musical group* appearing in Sahara (1-2) = `_A-HA_`
>  14. *Middle-Eastern Arabs* are nomadic people with no leader (6) = `(-r)OMANIS`
>  16. *Tools for measuring* - *leaders* (6) = `RULERS (ddef)`
>
>  **Down**
>  1. Maybe the awful weather's starting to pass, *evoking negative feelings* (7) = `(THE A(-w)FUL)*`
>  2. Contract man in supporting structures for *large computers* (10) = `MA_ + IN + FRAMES`
>  5. Cossacks secretly making *fire* (4) = `_SACK_`
>  6. *Stand-up guy* with a bit of gentlemen's character (6) = `_MENSCH_`
>  7. *Prisoner* making network's final appearance, ultimately (8) = `INTERNE(T -> _E)` (found by Omega Krypton)
>  12. *Tree's* - *remains after burning* (3) = `ASH (ddef)`
>  13. Lead-free, pure *gas containing nitrogen and oxygen* (3) = `(-f)AIR`
>  15. *Original Mad Max* held in homeland (3) = `_MEL_`

Comment: sniped :( d7: rot13(vagrearg -> svany yrggre punatrq gb _R, qrs=cevfbare)

Comment: I'll add in an explanation for the Hitori later if necessary, currently don't want to go through the pain of editing using Photoshop again

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Ah, that makes sense, given the "making" part, thanks!

Comment: All correct. Well done!

Comment: I was halfway solved this, good job!