# Double feature: Weightier

Tags: grid-deduction, cryptic-crosswords

<sub>This puzzle is part 7 of the Double feature series (first part [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90029)). The series will continue in "*[Double feature: Going postal](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90460)*".</sub>

---

> [image]
>
> Rules of **Statue View**<sup>1</sup>
>
> - Insert the four given pieces (`7`, `Y`, `t` and `G`) into the grid by shading some cells. Pieces can be rotated and reflected.
> - The numbered cells cannot be shaded.
> - Pieces cannot be adjacent to each other vertically or horizontally, but they may touch at a corner.
> - All unshaded cells must be orthogonally connected.
> - The numbers give the total lengths of shaded cells starting immediately adjacent to the numbered cell and extending outwards from it.
>
> **Across**
>   4. Strike is rescheduled, starting in the morning (3)
>   6. Morse-coded traditional customs (5)
>   7. Throw support for broken arm (5)
>   9. Gradual decline in web broadcasting (3)
>   12. Neon signs covering millions of years (4)
>   13. Predict knocking back unlimited drink (5)
>   14. Agent buried in Egypt's pyramids (3)
>   16. Inside of a simpleton (3)
>   19. Taiwan's mythological bird (3)
>   20. Outspoken deer man with goat's feet (4)
>   21. Perhaps a Persian carpet's surface has the first sign of abrasion (3)
>
> **Down**
>   1. Bother a starship captain after losing head (3)
>   2. Go after good French drum (5)
>   3. Break a downturn after charge is dropped (6)
>   5. Pleasant-sounding physician seen around large office's entrance (7)
>   8. Captured by generous dictator (4)
>   10. Youngster's corpse is missing part of heart (3)
>   11. Flaws of awards needing no introduction (5)
>   15. Unit essentially trapped in extreme terrain (4)
>   17. East African a great distance away (4)
>   18. Sample of a traditional stout (3)
>
> <sub><sup>1</sup> Paraphrased from the original rules on [Puzzling Stack Exchange](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84335).</sub>

Solve both puzzles to answer the question: **What does "weightier" mean?**

Comment: In my opinion, the `V` looks more like a `Y`.

Comment: @trolley813 Hm, I see what you mean. I changed it to Y. Although I suppose one could say that it looks a little bit like an upside-down A as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer is

> MORE SIGNIFICANT

Grids and Clues

> [image]
>  Note: A20 should be faUn instead of faWn. Sorry!

Explanation to Clues

> D1: (-k)IRK <sub>Thanks to @ChrisCudmore & @PiIsNot3</sub>
>  D2: BON+GO
>  D3: RECESS(-ion) <sub>Wordplay thanks to @ChrisCudmore</sub>
>  A4: R_+AM
>  D5: ME(L_O_)DIC
>  A6: *MORES
>  A7: SLING (ddef)
>  D8: _NERO_
>  A9: _EBB_
>  D10: BO(-d)Y
>  A11: (-o)SCARS
>  A12: _EONS_
>  A13: _CIDER_<
>  A14: _SPY_
>  D15: _P_+IN+T_
>  A16: O(A)F
>  D17: A+FAR <sub>Wordplay thanks to @ChrisCudmore</sub>
>  D18: _FAT_
>  D19: ROC (ddef)
>  A20: FAUN (hp ~fawn) <sub>Thanks to @ChrisCudmore</sub>
>  A21: C_(A_)_T[def=perhaps a Persian] <sub>Thanks to @ChrisCudmore</sub>

will continue later...

Comment: D1 is Rot13(vex) which is funny because both cleartext and rot13 fit the definition

Comment: A20 is rot13(snha) (homophone)

Comment: D17 Wordplay possibility Rot13(N + SNE [n terng qvfgnapr] = NSNE)

Comment: A21 rot13(P[N]G pnecrg fhesnpr = PG unf svefg bs Noenfvba)

Comment: D3 wordplay: rot13(ERPRFFVBA - VBA [punetr])

Comment: @ChrisCudmore D1 wordplay is rot13((-x)VEX)

Comment: In 20 across you have the correct answer, but the wrong word is written in the grid. Otherwise all correct.

Comment: doesn't the statue view have multiple solutions?  Exchange the top-left and the bottom-right piece.

Comment: @greenturtle3141 oh yea... im lucky then lol