# Double feature: Going postal

Tags: grid-deduction, cryptic-crosswords, printers-devilry

<sub>This puzzle is part 8 of the Double feature series (first part [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90029)). The series will continue in "*[Double feature: Unpopular](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90536)*".</sub>

---

> [image]
>
> Rules of **Yajilin**<sup>1</sup>
>
> - Shade some cells in the grid.
> - The numbered cells show how many shaded cells are in the direction of the arrow.
> - Shaded cells cannot be adjacent to another shaded cell.
> - Make a single loop which goes through every unshaded, unnumbered cell.
>
> Note: The crossword clues below are a mix of Printer's Devilry and normal cryptic clues.
>
> **Across**
>   1. Dr. Evans heading away from extremely beautiful woman (3)
>   7. Rand represented in Africa's primary monetary union, finally (3)
>   8. The band's vocalist also released two soles (6)
>   9. Part of London also holding prisoners (4)
>   10. What Hannibal spoke twisted in Clarice's head after turning up (5)
>   12. Response to Marco's shirt (4)
>   14. The South Auckland pub refused to allow Mary into the establishment (6)
>   15. This is a picture of the cataract, or pal as lassie (5)
>   16. The number of hashish? – Uge on Twitter (4)
>
> **Down**
>   2. Stalk with neighbours doesn't have to be boring (4)
>   3. A male person is climbing on a large house (7)
>   4. Fincher drops the case on Korean city (7)
>   5. Taking a position as artful musing (8)
>   6. There were 27 cakes as wedding to Charles (6)
>   11. The painting depicts him at the centre of the table surrounded by the twelve ales (4)
>   13. A glass has one kind of service (3)
>
> <sub><sup>1</sup> Paraphrased from the original rules on [Nikoli](https://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/yajilin.html).</sub>

Solve both puzzles to answer the question: **What can the postman bring?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The postman can bring

> a MAIL SHIPMENT.

Grids:

> [image]

Explanations of crossword clues:

> 1a. p.d. "Demure vans". 7a. A(-frica) (-monetar)Y (-unio)N. 8a. p.d. "solo singles". 9a. substring. 10a. PU<+IN*+C(-larice). 12a. Marco Polo. 14a. p.d. "Maori entry". 15a. p.d. "canine star actor". 16a. p.d. "hashtags is huge".
>  2d. p.d. "Small-talk". 3d. MAN+IS<+ON. 4d. (-f)INCHE(-r)+ON. 5d. AS+MUSING*. 6d. p.d. "cakes in Diana's wedding". 11d. p.d. "apostles". 13d. double def.

Credit where due: I had to abandon this with four of the clues (1a, 8a, 14a, 6d) still unsolved and while I was away Deusovi kindly supplied solutions to them all. Thanks, Deusovi!

Comment: rot13(1: qRZHer inaf / 8: fbYB FVATyrf / 6: VA QVNAn'f )

Comment: rot13(14: znBEV RAGel)

Comment: Nice! Will fill 'em in later -- am mostly AFK right now. [EDITED to add:] Now done. Thanks!

Comment: 1 across was actually intended as a non-PD clue, but this works (and produces the correct answer!) as well.

Comment: I'm glad, because "demure vans" doesn't make much sense to me. I have to admit I don't see any ordinary way to get to that answer, though. In fact, right now I can't see either a plausible definition or any bit of relevant wordplay :-).

Comment: I realize the puzzle is quite old but I think the intended answer for 1a might have been rot13(QERNZL zvahf QE R_)

Comment: That's a very plausible answer. Jafe said that what's currently here "works (and produces the correct answer!)" which isn't true if you're right, but I have to say my best guess is that you _are_ right and Jafe didn't look carefully enough at what answer I'd actually put down :-).