# Double feature: Unpopular

Tags: grid-deduction, cryptic-crosswords, mazes, nonogram

<sub>This puzzle is part 9 of the Double feature series (first part [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90029)). The series will continue in "*[Double feature: Health shakes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90725)*".</sub>

---

> [image]
>
> **Across**
>   2. A victory is found in path leading to hardship (7)
>   6. Biblical figure among Israelites (3)
>   7. Limits to wearing prisoner restraints (7)
>   8. Before a lecture's beginning, learner lead around in a kind of game (7)
>   10. Keen follower behind extremely famous artist, perhaps part of a club (3)
>   13. One dictatorial leader east of Central Africa! (3)
>   14. Computer's case includes insider-exclusive, leading processor chip for 9 down (5)
>   15. Facial features shown by votes against, expressed speaker initially (5)
>   16. Facial features shown by votes for, expressed speaker (4)
>
> **Down**
>   1. Washington Redskins training openers to produce growth (4)
>   2. Central station above Arctic struck the second before its introduction by an expert in organizing forces (9)
>   3. Terrible and not originally legal (5)
>   4. Not as much as the French steamboat (4)
>   5. One can be loaded to pass (3)
>   9. Top Brexiteers shake up UK citizens (5)
>   11. Large, not small, specimen (5)
>   12. Not the primary tool for metalworking (4)
>   14. Some music is transmitted to stone tomb (4)

Solve both puzzles to answer the question: **What can an unpopular decision do?**

Comment: what is the second puzzle called and what are its rules ?

Comment: @Nobody: Looks like a [Nonogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonogram).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An unpopular opinion might

> **AROUSE CRITICISM**

Solved cryptic crossword (with explanations) + nonogram:

> [image: unpopular_jafe]
>  **Across**
>  2. A victory is found in path leading to *hardship* (7)  = `TR(A + V)AIL`
>  6. *Biblical figure* among Israelites (3) = `_ELI_`
>  7. *Limits* to wearing prisoner restraints (7) = `CU(TO)FFS`
>  8. Before a lecture's beginning, learner lead around in *a kind of game* (7) = `P(IN)B + A_ + L_ + L`
>  10. Keen follower behind extremely famous artist, *perhaps part of a club* (3) = `F_ + A_ + _N`
>  13. *One dictatorial leader east of Central Africa!* (3) = `I + D_ + _(-r)I_ (&lit)`
>  14. Computer's case includes insider-exclusive, leading processor *chip for 9 down* (5) = `C_R + I_S + P_`
>  15. *Facial features* shown by votes against, expressed speaker initially (5) = `NOS + E_ + S_`
>  16. *Facial features* shown by votes for, expressed speaker (4) = `EYES (homophone for AYES)`
>
>  **Down**
>  1. Washington Redskins training openers to produce *growth* (4) = `WA + R_ + T_`
>  2. Central station above Arctic struck the second before its introduction by an *expert in organizing forces* (9) = `_T_ + A(-r)CTIC + I_ + AN`
>  3. *Terrible* and not originally legal (5) = `(-l)AWFUL`
>  4. *Not as much as* the French steamboat (4) = `LE + SS`
>  5. *One can be loaded* - *to pass* (3) = `DIE (ddef)`
>  9. Top Brexiteers shake up *UK citizens* (5) = `B_ + (STIR)<`
>  11. *Large*, not small, specimen (5) = `(-s)AMPLE`
>  12. *Not the primary* - *tool for metalworking* (4) = `VICE (ddef)`
>  14. Some music is transmitted to *stone tomb* (4) = `_CIST_`

To extract the phrase,

> solve each distinct section of the nonogram like a maze, as done above, then overlap on top of the crossword grid:
>  [image: unpopular_jafe_extraction]

Comment: Nice work! For 14 across the intended parsing was rot13(P(bzchgre)E+V(apyhqr)F+C(ebprffbe)).