# Double feature: Health shakes

Tags: grid-deduction, cryptic-crosswords, slitherlink

<sub>This puzzle is part 10 of the Double feature series (first part [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90029)). The series will continue in "*[Double feature: Computer problems](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90728)*".</sub>

---

> [image]
>
> Rules of **Slitherlink**<sup>1</sup>
>
> - Draw a single continuous loop in the grid, following cell borders.
> - The loop never branches off in multiple directions or crosses itself.
> - The numbers indicate how many lines belonging to the loop surround that cell. If no number is indicated, the cell may be surrounded by any number of lines.
>
> **Across**
>   2. Red camp ground lacking space (7)
>   5. Surge of water is eventually concealed (4)
>   7. Following a drain without delay (4)
>   8. In Spain, the primary official language (3)
>   9. Irish author's delight: finishing parts of Celtic tale (5)
>   13. Brew a lime peel (3)
>   14. A feline male chromosome (4)
>   15. Water of the first degree (5)
>
> **Down**
>   1. A gel spread almost too smoothly (6)
>   2. Leading lawyer follows California gangster's right-hand man… (4)
>   3. …as well as Capone's organization's head (4)
>   4. Hearing to take note of Mr. Chagall (4)
>   6. Father of 007 in a cast (3)
>   9. Giants share their home with black bears, at last (4)
>   10. Some mystery, enigmatic note from Tokyo (3)
>   11. Make an impression in ketchup (4)
>   12. Apple computer's physical address (3)
>   13. Dismiss a gender-neutral pronoun (3)
>
> <sub><sup>1</sup> Paraphrased from the original rules on [Nikoli](https://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/slitherlink.html).</sub>

Solve both puzzles to answer the question: **What are health shakes?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Health shakes are

> **MEAL REPLACEMENTS**

Solved cryptic crossword (with explanations) + Slitherlink:

> [image: health_shakes]
>  **Across**
>  2. Red camp ground *lacking space* (7) = `(RED CAMP)*`
>  5. *Surge* of water is eventually concealed (4) = `_RISE_`
>  7. Following a drain *without delay* (4) = `A + SAP`
>  8. In Spain, the primary official *language* (3) = `LA + O_`
>  9. *Irish author's* delight: finishing parts of Celtic tale (5) = `JOY + _C + _E`
>  13. *Brew* a lime peel (3) = `A + L_E`
>  14. *A feline* male chromosome (4) = `MAN + X`
>  15. *Water* - *of the first degree* (5) = `TONIC (ddef)`
>
>  **Down**
>  1. A gel spread almost too *smoothly* (6) = `(A GEL)* + TO_`
>  2. Leading lawyer follows California gangster's right-hand *man*… (4) = `CA + _R + L_`
>  3. …*as well as* Capone's organization's head (4) = `ALS + O_`
>  4. Hearing to take note of *Mr. Chagall* (4) = `MARC (homophone of MARK)`
>  6. *Father of 007* in a cast (3) = `(IN A)*`
>  9. *Giants share their home with* black bears, at last (4) = `JET + _S`
>  10. Some mystery, enigmatic *note from Tokyo* (3) = `_YEN_`
>  11. *Make an impression* in ketchup (4) = `_ETCH_`
>  12. *Apple computer's* - *physical address* (3) = `MAC (ddef)`
>  13. *Dismiss* a gender-neutral pronoun (3) = `A + XE`

To extract the phrase,

> overlap the Slitherlink path on the crossword grid, then take all the letters not inside the loop, excluding the ones outside the 9x9 grid, and read from left to right, top to bottom:
>  [image: health_shakes_sol]

Comment: All correct. Nice work!