# Double feature: Computer problems

Tags: grid-deduction, cryptic-crosswords

<sub>This puzzle is part 11 of the Double feature series (first part [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90029)). The series will continue in "*[Double feature: Bibliophile edition](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90756)*".</sub>

---

> [image]
>
> Rules of **Statue Park**<sup>1</sup>
>
> - Insert eleven of the depicted L-tromino pieces into the grid.
> - Pieces can be rotated or reflected.
> - Pieces cannot be adjacent to another piece, but they may touch at a corner.
> - Empty cells are all connected.
> - Cells marked with a black circle must be part of a piece.
> - Cells marked with a white circle must be empty.
>
> **Across**
>   1. Sauce for diplomatic leaders (3)
>   3. Sun god with head of Merino sheep (3)
>   6. See scales turning nonstop (9)
>   7. Return of divine being Anubis, depicted with one's head (3)
>   9. Go change the direction of Fourth Street (4)
>   12. I think I am nothing (3)
>   13. President is out after prisoners (4)
>   15. The one and only part of the human body (4)
>   16. Honorific held by Osiris (3)
>
> **Down**
>   1. Pass judgment for Seth's crime: No "eye for eye" (6)
>   2. Ptah at odds with Asarte's last seed (3)
>   3. Hungry elephant sampling cereal (3)
>   4. Israeli intelligence contracted to plant in 14 down (4)
>   5. Half of judgment is getting reversed? No comments (8)
>   8. Graphical user interface design: Starters handbook (5)
>   10. Helicopter part going up and down (5)
>   11. The twisted letter with stroke (3)
>   14. Mostly fictitious wetland (3)
>
> <sub><sup>1</sup> Paraphrased from the original rules on [Melon's Puzzles](https://mellowmelon.wordpress.com/statue-park/).</sub>

Solve both puzzles to answer the question: **What do computers need?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Computers need

> PROCESSING UNITS

as we can see:

> [image]

Explanations of clues:

> 1a. DIP(-lomatic). 3a. RA+M(-erino). 6a. SEESCALES*. 7a. GOD<. 9a. Triple def (third is a poker reference). 12a. IM+O; abbr. 13a. substring. 15a. double def. 16. substring.
>  1d. DE(-i)CIDE. (I confess I don't know what Seth is meant here.) 2d. P(-t)A(-h) containing (-astart)E. 3d. substring. 4d. MOSS(-ad). 5d. (-judg)MENT + IS containing NO<. 8d. GUI+DE(-sign). 10d. ROTOR is a palindrome. 11d. THE*. 14d. BOG(-us).

(Of course I didn't look at NudgeNudge's answers, posted while I was completing this.)

Credit where due: Thanks to Alconja for figuring out the third part of the triple definition in 9a.

Comment: Great job! :) Way faster than me

Comment: I always feel I have to attack these quickly, because there are some other really quick solvers around. Fortunately Deusovi is probably asleep right now :-).

Comment: I think you must be right about 9a being a triple def, rot13(Tb ("vg'f lbhe ghea/tb") + punatr gur qverpgvba bs + sbhegu fgerrg (gur sbhegu pbzzhany pneq cynlrq va cbxre, nyfb xabja nf gur ghea))

Comment: Ah, it's my poker knowledge that was deficient. Will edit. Thanks!

Comment: Nice work! The crime I had in mind for 1 down is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osiris_myth), although it could be that the perpetrator is is more commonly referred to without the final H.

Comment: Duh, of course! Thanks. (And yes, I always think of his name as Set rather than Seth.)