# Double features: The wrap-up

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, geography, metapuzzles

<sub>This puzzle is the final part of the Double feature series (first part [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90029)).</sub>
<sub>**Note**: This answers **gives away the answers** to previous puzzles.</sub>

---

> [image]

The answers to the twelve Double feature puzzles are listed below. (Spoilers ahead – you've been warned twice now.) Use the answers and the given grid to answer the question: **Where are we?**

> scariest monsters
>  mole species
>  unaccompanied solo
>  sauna's temperature
>  animal mitochondria
>  hasten foreclosure
>  more significant
>  mail shipment
>  arouse criticism
>  meal replacements
>  processing units
>  successive pairs

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In each answer:

> One of the two words anagrams to a national capital.

As hinted by the given image:

> The capitals should be sorted from west to east. Then, every answer has a word left over, which should also be considered.

So, when this is done:

> `sauna's temperature  - NASSAU, the bahamas / Temperature    77.4°W
>  mail shipment        - LIMA, peru          / sHipment       77.0°W
>  arouse criticism     - ROSEAU, dominica    / crIticism      61.4°W
>  scariest monsters    - CASTRIES, st lucia  / monSters       60.9°W
>  mole species         - LOMÉ, togo          / specIes         1.2°E
>  successive pairs     - PARIS, france       / succeSsive      2.3°E
>  processing units     - TUNIS, tunisia      / procesSing     10.2°E
>  unaccompanied solo   - OSLO, norway        / unaccomPanied  10.7°E
>  more significant     - ROME, italy         / significAnt    12.5°E
>  hasten foreclosure   - ATHENS, greece      / foreclosuRe    23.7°E
>  meal replacements    - MALÉ, maldives      / replacemenTs   73.5°E
>  animal mitochondria  - MANILA, philippines / mitochondriA  121.0°E` 
>
>
>  Reading down the diagonal of the remaining words (first letter of the first, second letter of the second, etc.) spells **THIS IS SPARTA**.

Comment: This is correct. Nice job!

Comment: Of course, if it doesn't make sense why this was the answer, I'll admit that the entire thing was purely [self](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/300_(film))-[celebratory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKaHQ.png) :)